# How to deal with an apostrophe while writing into a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the  right syntax to use near 's','portal','','offering','MSNBC','News','','sports','','MSN','Money','','games'' at line 3

The only problem is that this error shows up when inserting data that contains an apostrophe. I tried changing the data type from `VARCHAR` to `TEXT`, but the result is still the same.

I tried to put in `addslashes()`

How do I fix this?

```
$query=" INSERT INTO alltags
 (id,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6,tag7,tag8,tag9,tag10,tag11,tag12,tag13,tag14,tag15,tag16,tag17,tag18,tag19,tag20,tag21,tag22,tag23,tag24,tag25,tag26,tag27,tag28,tag29,tag30)
VALUES      
 ('',mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[0]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[1]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[2]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[3]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[4]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[5]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[6]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[7]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[8]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[9]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[10]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[11]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[12]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[13]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[14]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[15]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[16]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[17]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[18]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[19]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[20]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[21]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[22]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[23]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[24]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[25]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[26]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[27]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[28]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[29])) "; 
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I changed it to `mysql_real_escape_string`. Is this syntax correct? I am getting errors.

Comment: id is an auto_increment so I left it blank

Comment: Use PDO...it'll solve two problems at once.  http://php.net/pdo

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The process of encoding data which contains characters MySQL might interpret is called "escaping". You must escape your strings with `mysql_real_escape_string`, which is a PHP function, not a MySQL function, meaning you have to run it in PHP before you pass your query to the database. You *must* escape any data that comes into your program from an external source. Any data that isn't escaped is a potential [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You have to escape your data *before* you build your query. Also, you can build your query programmatically using PHP's looping constructs and [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
// Build tag fields
$tags = 'tag' . implode(', tag', range(1,30));

// Escape each value in the uniqkey array
$values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $uniqkey);

// Implode values with quotes and commas
$values = "'" . implode("', '", $values) . "'";

$query = "INSERT INTO alltags (id, $tags) VALUES ('', $values)";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Conceptually, this makes a lot of sense. I am still trying to incorporate your code into mine. thanks for your input

Comment: @Karthik The important thing is that you realize that `mysql_real_escape_string` is run in PHP, before you ever pass your data to `mysql_query`. I'm not sure how OMG Ponies got that one so wrong...

Comment: [Function *mysql_real_escape_string()* was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and was removed in PHP 7.0.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 13):

Using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is a safer approach to handling characters for SQL insertion/updating:

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE
VALUES
  (mysql_real_escape_string($var1),
   mysql_real_escape_string($var2))
```

Also, I'd change your columns back from TEXT to VARCHAR - searching, besides indexing, works much better.

### Update for your update

Being that `id` is an auto_increment column you can:

- leave it out of the list of columns, so you don't have to provide a value in the VALUES clause:

  ```
  INSERT INTO alltags
    (tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6,tag7,tag8,tag9,tag10,tag11,tag12,tag13,tag14,tag15,tag16,tag17,tag18,tag19,tag20,tag21,tag22,tag23,tag24,tag25,tag26,tag27,tag28,tag29,tag30)
  VALUES      
    (mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[0]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[1]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[2]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[3]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[4]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[5]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[6]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[7]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[8]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[9]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[10]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[11]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[12]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[13]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[14]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[15]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[16]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[17]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[18]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[19]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[20]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[21]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[22]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[23]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[24]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[25]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[26]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[27]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[28]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[29])) ";
  ```
- include `id` in the list of columns, which requires you use either value in its place in the VALUES clause:

  - `NULL`
  - `DEFAULT`

Here's an example using NULL as the id placeholder:

```
INSERT INTO alltags
  (id,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6,tag7,tag8,tag9,tag10,tag11,tag12,tag13,tag14,tag15,tag16,tag17,tag18,tag19,tag20,tag21,tag22,tag23,tag24,tag25,tag26,tag27,tag28,tag29,tag30)
 VALUES      
  (NULL,mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[0]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[1]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[2]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[3]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[4]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[5]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[6]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[7]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[8]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[9]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[10]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[11]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[12]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[13]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[14]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[15]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[16]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[17]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[18]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[19]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[20]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[21]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[22]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[23]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[24]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[25]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[26]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[27]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[28]),mysql_real_escape_string($uniqkey[29])) ";
```

I want to ***really*** stress that you should not setup your columns like that.

Comment: I edited my question. Is there anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: @Ponies: This code is really wrong. I will investigate who gave you four upvotes and kill them too. You cannot mix PHP function calls into an SQL string. You have to break out of the "string" and call .mysql_real_escape(). separately for each variable.

Comment: @Ponies Please fix this. It's wrong on so many level!

Comment: [Function *mysql_real_escape_string()* was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and was removed in PHP 7.0.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 8):

Slight improvement of meagar's answer:

**EDIT:** *meagar updated his post, so his answer is now better.*

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO alltags (id, ';

// append tag1, tag2, etc.
$query .= 'tag' . implode(', tag', range(1, 30)) . ") VALUES ('', ";

// escape each value in the uniqkey array
$escaped_tags = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $uniqkey);

// implode values with quotes and commas, and add closing bracket
$query .= "'" . implode("', '", $escaped_tags) . "')";

// actually query
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: +1 Like the way you build the tags string; it is late, and I am tired.

Answer (score 4):

Please look at meagars answer. This is the correct code.

If you want to use the misguided mysql_query() function, then you have to break up the SQL string  as follows:

```
mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO whateever (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES ("
    . mysql_real_escape_string($col1) 
    . ","
    . mysql_real_escape_string($col2) 
    . ","       
    . mysql_real_escape_string($col3) 
    . ","
    . mysql_real_escape_string($col4) 
    . ")"
);
```

Or since you have an array, use the clever method call to escape all at once:

```
$uniqkey = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $uniqkey);

mysql_query("USE THE ESCAPED ARRAY THEN DIRECTLY ('$uniqkey[0]', '$uniqkey[1]', '$uniqkey[2]', '$uniqkey[3]', ...");
```